# Good practice way of getting items with subitems from the database and displaying them

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a list of items. For each item there are sublists. It is kind of like the answers on StackOverflow where each answer has a list of 0-n subcomments.

I am using a PHP script, and I am able to query for all the comments and subcomments in one query, but having a hard time organizing the data to be displayed properly.

The difficulty I am having is getting all the main comments, then aggregating all the subcomments under them, and then dynamically figuring out when to place the form to add extra subcomments.

Any idea how to do this in a more or less elegant or good-practice manner?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have parent_id for each item it's easy with references

example from my code

```
/**
    * array for storing data
    *
    * @var array
    */
private $tree = array();
   /**
    * html - output of current module
    *
    * @var string
    */
    private $output = ''; 

  /**
   * Retreives data from table items.
   *
   * @return void
   */
    private function _getData()
{
    $pdo = App_Registry::get('pdo');
    $levels = array();
    foreach ($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM sellers ORDER BY parent_id ASC',PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $k=>$v){
               //tree with references references
         $current =  &$levels[ $v->id ] ;
             $current['parent_id'] = $v->parent_id;
             $current['name'] = $v->name;
             if (0 == $v->parent_id){
             $this->tree[ $v->id ] = &$current;
             } else {
         $levels[$v->parent_id ]['children'][$v->id] = &$current;
             }
    }
}   

/*
*App_AbstractModule::preRender overriding
    * @return void
*/
protected  function preRender()
{
    $this->_getData();
    }
  /**
   * recursively build html output.
   *
   * @return string
   */
private function _render($arr)
{
    $this->output.= '<ul>';
    foreach ($arr as $k=>$v)
    {
        $this->output.= '<li>'.$v['name'].'</li>';
        if( !empty($v['children'])){
            $this->_render($v['children']);
        }
    }
    $this->output.= '</ul>';
    return $this->output;
}
/*
*App_AbstractModule::render overriding
    * @return string
*/
protected  function render()
{
        return $this->_render($this->tree);
}
```

}

table looks next way

```
   id   parent_id   name
    1   0   Dave Brubeck
    2   0   Ahmad Jamal
    3   0   Art Blacky
    4   0   Roy Hargrov
    5   2   Miles Davis
    6   1   Richie Cole
    7   2   Dizzy Gillespie
    8   5   Joshua Redman
    9   1   Michel Petrucciani
```

Answer (score 1):

When faced with this problem I have usually built two arrays from my query: one of the main comments and then one of all the subcomments. Then I loop through the main comments and using some related keys pull in the subcomments when they are present. Its not great because of o(n^2) but for small jobs its not a big deal.

Comment: this is what I was thinking too.  Thanks!

Comment: This also will let you know when you don't have or have run out of subcomments so you will know when to put in your comment box.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to do this that "sits right" with me is to read the whole lot out of the database into a DOMDocument to convert it to XML - you can then use standard DOM navigation techniques to traverse the nodes (useful if you only want to pass the ID of the currently viewed "page" around in the URL).

For instance you can start with the last node in the list and go "up" the list until 'parent_id' (for instance) == 0;

Comment: this is a good idea actually...but I think doing it in xml might be a bit of a pain lol I will try the other solution posted, and if its too troublesome, I'll try your idea.

Comment: Wouldn't the xml generation be expensive though?

Comment: @MichaelDillon - it does have an overhead but you could generate it from a CMS whenever you update the database and save it as a text file either in HTML or XML format (with an XSLT). That way you're only updating it as and when you change something and you're actually reducing calls to the database from the website which reduces the bottleneck there ... it's all a bit swings and roundabouts though.

Comment: ... Basically you have to decide whether the DOMDocument overhead is less than that of nested recursive loops and database calls, which really depends on the depth of the nesting. If you're doing a navigation system with only 2 levels then the loops are probably OK - if it's more along the lines of an old-skool threaded message board you'll probably get less of a performance hit using DOMDocument.